# DataReader Hololens

Tags: c#, udp, datareader, hololens, stream-socket-client

I'm trying to create a udp client/server on Hololens. My idea behind the project is to have a communication between an iOS app and the Hololens. Here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
    using Windows.Networking;
    using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
    using Windows.Storage.Streams;
#endif

public class server : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text monTexte;

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
        StreamSocket socket;
        StreamSocketListener listener;
        String port;
        String message;
#endif

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
        listener = new StreamSocketListener();
        port = "12345";
        listener.ConnectionReceived += Listener_ConnectionReceived;
        listener.Control.KeepAlive = false;

        Listener_Start();
#endif
    }

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
    private async void Listener_Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Listener started");
        try
        {
            await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(port);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error: " + e.Message);
        }

        Debug.Log("Listening");
    }

    private async void Listener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.Log("Connection received");

        try
        {
            while (true) {

                    using (var dw = new DataWriter(args.Socket.OutputStream))
                    {
                        dw.WriteString("salut");
                        await dw.StoreAsync();
                        dw.DetachStream();
                    }  

                    using (var dr = new DataReader(args.Socket.InputStream))
                    {
                        var receivedStrings = "";

                        while (dr.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
                        {
                            uint bytesToRead = dr.ReadUInt32();
                            receivedStrings += dr.ReadString(bytesToRead) + "\n";
                            Debug.Log(receivedStrings);
                            monTexte.text = receivedStrings;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("iPhone disconnected!!!!!!!! " + e);
        }

    }

#endif
}
```

I managed to send messages, now I don't know why I never receive messages from client...
I created a DataReader but it seems to never listen. Any idea ? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I found the way to solved it, here is my full code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
    using Windows.Networking;
    using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
    using Windows.Storage.Streams;
#endif

public class server : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text monTexte;
    public String _input = "Waiting";

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
        StreamSocket socket;
        StreamSocketListener listener;
        String port;
        String message;
#endif

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
        listener = new StreamSocketListener();
        port = "12345";
        listener.ConnectionReceived += Listener_ConnectionReceived;
        listener.Control.KeepAlive = false;

        Listener_Start();
#endif
    }

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
    private async void Listener_Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Listener started");
        try
        {
            await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(port);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error: " + e.Message);
        }

        Debug.Log("Listening");
    }

    private async void Listener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.Log("Connection received");

        try
        {
            while (true) {

                    using (var dw = new DataWriter(args.Socket.OutputStream))
                    {
                        dw.WriteString("salut");
                        await dw.StoreAsync();
                        dw.DetachStream();
                    }  

                    using (var dr = new DataReader(args.Socket.InputStream))
                    {
                        dr.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
                        await dr.LoadAsync(12);
                        var input = dr.ReadString(12);
                        Debug.Log("received: " + input);
                        _input = input;

                    }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("iPhone disconnected!!!!!!!! " + e);
        }

    }

#endif

     void Update() {
        monTexte.text = _input;
    }
}
```